# How do I get muliple shouldStartLoadWithRequest events

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad

I'm loading an html document in a UIWebView in an ipad application.  It has one button that executes the following javascript

```
function myfunc() {
    var i = 10;
    while(i--)
    {
        windows.location.href = i;
    }
}
```

I implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol as follows:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:z(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)
{
     NSLog(@"request = %@",[request description]);
}
```

When I press the button 
I only get the last value of  i come in the request variable.  It's as if the javascript method must return before the delegate method gets called.  I would expect it to get called 10 times.  Is there any way to make this happen?